# Setting up TileStache

Tags: tiles, mapnik, geojson

I want to set up TileStache, but I'm new enough to the world of GIS to find the [TileStache docs](http://tilestache.org/doc/) a bit impenetrable.

I've just about figured out that I need to run

```
tilestache-server.py -c tilestache.cfg
```

to start TileStache, and navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8080/ to see the results.

However, I'm unclear on what to put in `tilestache.cfg`.

Eventually I want to use GeoJSON, generated from a PostGIS database, but for now I'd just like to start with a simple example to make sure that TileStache is working.

There is [a 'minimal sample configuration' in the docs, but it seems to rely on Mapnik](http://tilestache.org/doc/#configuring-tilestache) - and refers to a `style.xml` file - do I need to install and configure Mapnik before I can use TileStache?

*** UPDATE ***

Okay, I've tried using a 'proxy' config as follows in `tilestache.cfg`:

```
{
  "cache":  {"name": "Test"},
  "layers":
  {
    "roads":
    {
      "provider":
      {
        "name": "proxy", 
        "url": "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.png"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then restarting Tilestache and going to http://127.0.0.1:8080/, but I still see:

```
Bad path: "/". I was expecting something more like "/example/0/0/0.png"
```

If I go to http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/0/0/0.png then I get a 404 - any ideas?

*** UPDATE 2 ***

For the benefit of others: `roads` should be part of the URL, so visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/roads/0/0/0.png or http://127.0.0.1:8080/roads/preview.html to see tiles!

Comment: That right... nice one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From browsing the documentation, it looks like Mapnik is just one of the possible providers. For your simple test, you could try the Proxy provider example (in the [Providers](http://tilestache.org/doc/#providers) section) which pulls and caches tiles from OpenStreetMap.

For your final goal, it looks like you'll want to use the Vector provider with your GeoJSON data.

Comment: thanks - I've tried with the Proxy provider (see update), but still no luck.

Comment: Ah okay figured it out - `roads` should be part of the URL - http://127.0.0.1:8080/roads/preview.html works. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, good to know. Glad to see you got something working!